# CMS Битрикс, Delphi и навигаторы

Tags: delphi, cms, битрикс

Кто нибудь работал с CMS Битрикс? Если да, то какие сложности возникали с ней, и что необходимо знать при работе (ответ все - нежелателен). Можно ли, не работав ни с одной CMS (только подключение модулей и т.д. без редактирования внутреннего кода) программировать в Битриксе?

Delphi и навигаторы (GPS, ГЛОНАСС): что в них общего? Какая связь? Программирование в этой области сильно трудно? В чем его специфика?

Answer (score 2):

По битриксу - очень хорошо знать php и погуглить на тему структуры каталогов, "как создать свой компонент на битрикс", внимательно просмотреть его таблицы. Работаю в основном с джумлой и реже с битриксом, вот у второго структура кода намного более прозрачная (без особых усилий можно связать два шаблона, из одного компонента вызвать другой etc). Но в битриксе просто очень много всего, в т.ч. в 95% случаев лишнего для сайта, и довольно редко, но все же встречается дикий быдлокод а ля

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$ac = count($a);    
for ($i = 0; $i < $ac; $i++):
  echo $a[$i];
  echo ' ';
  endfor;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ну какой нужен уровень программирования чтоб быстро освоиться в этой CMS?

Comment: Вообще там все довольно просто, уровень программирования - чуть выше среднего, алгоритмы простые в стиле php3-4, главные навыки - ориентироваться в чужом коде и быстро бегать по папкам)) У него учень муторно разложены файлы, встречаются пути типа "`bitrix/components/bitrix/menu/templates/plain[...]`"

ЗЫ: у меня он был первой ЦМС и адекватное понимание пришло через пару месяцев, до этого тупо правил шаблоны, даже свою папку в корне завел для подключения.

Comment: Да. Пути жутковатые  что и говорить

Answer (score 2):

Самый легкий для старта из популярных, на мой взгляд, WordPress (маленький, хорошо документированный, много существующих наработок). Но можно и другие CMS пощупать. В битрикс без особой нужды, я бы сходу не лез.

> Delphi и навигаторы (GPS, ГЛОНАСС) что в низ общего? какая связь? программирование в этой области сильно трудно? в чем его специфика?

Ничего. Но никто не запрещает написать на дельфе программу, которая общается с навигатором через RS-232 или USB. Как и на любом другом языке программирования. У гармина, например, все расписано [Device Interface SDK](http://www8.garmin.com/support/commProtocol.html)

ЗЫ. Разделяйте вопросы, не валите в кучу битрикс и навигаторы!

Comment: Вот именно что сообщается через юзб. Просто там уже идет управление устройствами или что то другое?

Comment: Да, вам просто нужна девелоперская документация на конкретный навигатор, описание протоколов.

Comment: И что с ними? смотрел вашу ссылку http://www8.garmin.com/support/commProtocol.html куча всего непонятногог и на инглише - неизвестно что и как куда применять

Comment: Там конкретно SDK для работы с гарминами и документация по протоколу. Я кинул ссылку в качестве примера, как это обычно выглядит. Какой навигатор у вас, никто из присутствующих не знает. 

На низком уровне обычно все сводится к тому, что вы подготавливаете в соответствии с протоколом команду в виде массива байтов, пишете ее в COM-порт (или в USB, не суть). Устройство вам на это отвечает, и вы считываете из порта массив байтов с ответом, потом разбираете его.

Comment: В частности, для работы с COM-портом на дельфи можно использовать стандартные средства WinAPI (CreateFile, ReadFile, WriteFile), можно через библиотечки типа Comm32 или SynaSer. получить представление о работе с USB из Delphi можно тут: http://pblog.ru/?p=105.

Поскольку у разных производителей разные спецификации протоколов, без уточнения задачи более подробно вам тут вряд ли кто-то ответит.

Answer (score 2):

Работал. Жутко тормозная и навороченная система, но с серьезным подходом к безопасности. Пользователи этой CMS редко используют более 50% ее функционала, а деньги за него все равно платят. Чтобы освоиться в коде Битрикса, надо хотя бы знать его [API](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/).

> Можно ли не работав ни с одной CMS (только тупое подключение модулей и тд без редактирования внутреннего кода) программировать в Битриксе.?

Вопрос из области "Можно ли обучиться javascript, если знаешь только php". Можно, но на это потребуется время.
П.С. А вопрос про навигаторы лучше запостить отдельно.

Answer (score 2):

Знаете, я "покопался в битриксе". Убило наличие в официальной документации описание MVC и вызова класса из модуля. Для второго переменную, служащую экземпляром класса, нужно сделать глобальной! Чесслово, курил не я, а разработчики.

А вообще, система большая, очень сильно навороченная, как говорят тесты, даже супер-пупер защищённая. Но я бы выбирал CMS под конкретную задачу. Иногда проще самому подключить фреймворк и написать 1-2-3 модуля, а когда-то нужны "монстры", вроде Drupal.

п.с. Если надумаете изучать битрикс, то забудьте подходы к программированию, которые у вас были до этого! (с) почти цитата из оф.доков.

Answer (score 1):

Не советую связываться с битриксом, есть много других CMS. NetCat к примеру.

Comment: Почему не советуете? Просто вакансия есть программист для ьитрикс, но я его в глаза не видел. А в Друпале не ковырялся, а просто сайт из модулей делал - но это скорее для ознакомления было.

Comment: т.е. вы увидели вакансию, требующую от сотрудника знаний, которых у вас нет, загорелись и решили быстренько стать сеньером девелопером?

Answer (score 1):

Для общение с USB,COM портом можно использовать библиотеку 
[BPort](http://kladovka.net.ru/index.cgi?pid=list&rid=295)

Подходить для Delphi 7

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы начать работать с битриксом, в принципе, мало чего из php надо знать. Интуитивно можно понять, как с помощью готовых модулей (просто перетаскивая их на страницу) и немного настроив их, можно собрать готовый сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Работаю с битриксом до сих пор, 99% тормозов от неумения настроить систему, большинство считает что после установки сайт готов. Второй камень преткновения это знание API битрикса, потому что с просто php можно идти домой.